# Smallest subgroup of $A_{5}$ containing the permutation $(12)(13)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

I need to find the smallest subgroup of $A_{5}$ that contains the permutation $(12)(13)$ and to also explain why.
I guess we can write this permutation as $(123)$ and I guess, according to a list of subgroups that I found, that the smallest would be $A_{3}$ in $A_{5}$.

If somebody could help me out with some reasoning or hints to understand this, I would appreciate it a lot.

It's important to say that this is my first ever algebra course, so it could be nice if the help would be kept simple and understandable for beginners.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $A_3=C_3$ is cyclic. So the cyclic group generated by $(123)$ is the smallest subgroup of $S_3$ containing $(123)$.

Comment: But why can we say that it is the smallest? I mean I saw it in a list somewhere online but what would be a explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group and $x\in G$. Then the smallest subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $x$ is the cyclic group $H=\langle x\rangle$ generated by $x$. It consists of all integral powers $x^n$ of $x$.

Here we have $G=S_3$ and
$$H=\langle (123) \rangle =\{(1),(123),(132)\}\cong C_3\cong A_3.$$

Answer (score 3):

$(123)$ has order $3$ and as a result generates a copy of $\mathbb Z_3$ in $A_5$.  You're right that this is $A_3$.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that,  order of the element $(12)(13)=(132)\ne(123)$ is 3.
Therefore, there are only 3 elements in the smallest subgroup containing $(12)(13)$
The required group is the one that generated by (12)(13), consisting of $(12)(13),((12)(13))^2$ and the identity permutation.

Comment: Thanks! So my approach was false.. but according to the list here https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A5 still the smallest group containing $(132)$ would be $A_3$ in $A_5$, or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: $A_3$ is a 3 element subgroup of $S_3$, in fact the only 3 element subgroup. Hence they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating $(12)(13)$ from right to left gives $(132)$, which has order three. By [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), then, the order of the smallest subgroup $H$ must be divisible by three. But, indeed, if we take $H=\langle (132)\rangle$ to be the (cyclic) subgroup of $A_5$ generated by $(132)$, we achieve the lowest such order.

You were right, too, in a sense, since $H$ is [*isomorphic*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20a%20group,respects%20the%20given%20group%20operations.&text=From%20the%20standpoint%20of%20group,and%20need%20not%20be%20distinguished.) (but not *equal*) to $\Bbb Z_3$ trivially, which, in turn, is isomorphic (but not *equal*) to $A_3$ by rotating the vertices of an equilateral triangle.